# jahia 7.0 template editing support

Tags: jahia

jahia 7.0 template editing doesn't work on linux env. It gives error on template creation from admin studio.

```
Cause level : 0 (level 0 is the most precise exception)
org.jahia.ajax.gwt.client.service.GWTJahiaServiceException:
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/jahia/maven3.0.4/bin" 
(in directory "/home/jahia/jahia70/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/var/sources"): 
error=13, Permission denied
```

Answer (score 2):

Bharat,

you need to edit Jahia.properties and fill in the full path name to your maven binary, example:

mvnPath = /opt/local/maven3/bin/mvn

I noticed that the installer fill's in the directory, but jahia needs to maven executable, similar to the svnPath and gitPath.
Obviously what Pat aid, the permissions need to work out, but usually this should be good.

After this it should work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the user who run maven command doesn't have permissions for /home/jahia/jahia70/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/var/sources.

Maybe you can check:

- The permissions of : /home/jahia/jahia70/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/var/sources
- The user who run the Jahia process (Jahia process could be : tomcat process or jboss process or maybe somethnig else)    (in my case it's : tomcat user)

And change the permissions considering that.

Answer (score 0):

It was issue of maven path. path should be upto maven executable.

```
mvnPath = /opt/local/maven3/bin/mvn
```